# redmine rest api post method with php

Tags: php, rest

i'm trying to add a new user to redmine using REST api :

```
<?php
  $service_url = "https://pmt.proxym-it.tn?key=9ed507d365eaa598a0f134c3eeb3efa062eb72de&method=POST&format=json";
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  $curl_post_data = array('user' =>     array("lastname"=>'Lachtar',"firstname"=>'Abdelfetteh',"login"=>'fetteh',"mail"=>'abdelfett ehlachtar@yahoo.fr',"password"=>'secret'));
  $curl_post_data = json_encode($curl_post_data);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
  }
  curl_close($curl);
  $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
  if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
  }
  echo 'response ok!';
  var_export($decoded);
?>
```

but the response returned is null.

Comment: do a `var_dump` before you call `json_decode` and see what you get.

Comment: i get this :Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Back

Comment: So you have a server error somewhere. That's the issue. Check your log files.

Comment: i have changed the url:
$service_url = "https://pmt.proxym-it.tn?key=9ed507d365eaa598a0f134c3eeb3efa062eb72de&method=POST&format=json";
the response still null but there is no server error

Comment: Can you please print $curl_response first? What is shows?

Comment: it shows : Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Back

Comment: and the log file shows :Started POST "/?key=9ed507d365eaa598a0f134c3eeb3efa062eb72de&method=POST&format=json" for 172.16.10.82 at Thu Apr 17 11:00:29 +0100 2014
Processing by WelcomeController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"key"=>"9ed507d365eaa598a0f134c3eeb3efa062eb72de", "method"=>"POST", "{\"user\":{\"lastname\":\"Lachtar\",\"firstname\":\"Abdelfetteh\",\"login\":\"fetteh\",\"mail\":\"abdelfettehlachtar@yahoo.fr\",\"password\":\"sec...
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
please help !

Comment: @abdelfetteh did you get any solution ? i am in same problem, if anything please share .

Answer (score 0):

when using

```
  http://username:password@localhost:9000
```

as url, its showing same error response ok!NULL but in redmine log its showing the following

```
 Parameters: {"{\"user\":{\"lastname\":\"test\",\"firstname\":\"rest\",\"login\":\"rest\",\"mail\":\"rest@test.com\",\"password\":\"12345678\"}}"=>"[FILTERED]", "method"=>"POST"}
 Current user: anonymous
 Filter chain halted as :check_if_login_required rendered or redirected
 Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3.3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: i solve the problem by using "php-redmine-api-master" ;)